# Topological semi-direct products of groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gr.group-theory, topological-groups

In [Kaniuth, Taylor, Induced representations of locally compact groups](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1263.22005) on pages 9-10 it's claimed that if $G$ is a locally compact group with closed subgroups $N,H$, with $N$ normal in $G$, with $N\cap H=\{e\}$, and with $NH=G$, then $G$ is a topological semidirect product of $N$ and $H$.

We copy the [algebraic proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product), defining an action $\alpha_h(n) = hnh^{-1}$ which will be suitably continuous, allowing us to construct $N \rtimes_\alpha H$.  The map $N \rtimes_\alpha H \rightarrow G; (n,h) \mapsto nh$ is an isomorphism of groups, and clearly continuous.

> Why is the inverse of this map continuous?

You would need to show that given nets $(n_i)\subseteq N, (h_i)\subseteq H$ with $n_ih_i\rightarrow e$, then necessarily $n_i\rightarrow e, h_i\rightarrow e$.  I don't see how to do this.

(Under some conditions, e.g. that $N \rtimes_\alpha H$ is $\sigma$-compact, there are open mapping theorems for locally compact groups available, which would show this.  For example, see Corollary 1.7 in [Hofmann, Morris, Open Mapping Theorem for Topological Groups (pdf)](https://sidneymorris.net/Morris141.pdf).)

(Also [asked on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4479990/topological-semi-direct-products) but without a conclusive answer.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a counterexample:

let $K$ be an infinite compact group, and $K^\delta$ be $K$ with the discrete topology.

Let $G$ be $K^\delta\times K$, let $N$ be equal to $K^\delta\times\{0\}$ and let $H$ be the diagonal. Then both $N,H$ are discrete, $G=NH$, $N\cap H=\{1\}$. But the canonical continuous group isomorphism $N\rtimes H\to G$ is not a topological isomorphism, since $G$ is not discrete.